# Is it forbidden (haram) to hate my own country?

Tags: fiqh, sin, halal-haram

I hate my own country (where I born) because it's very dirty everywhere, the streets and buildings and landscapes are NOT nice-looking. I love western countries (which are clean).

In Islam, is it forbidden (or haram) to HATE my own birth-place?

Comment: is there anyone who can answer please?

Comment: anyone please? :( :( :(

Comment: If you don’t like your country, visit Romania, it has one of the most beautiful landscapes, or USA, you can visit Arizona there and see what you can find. You can make one way travel if you want to. You can hate or love your country, it’s your choice that.

Comment: In Islam, is it forbidden (or haram) to HATE my own birth-place? Can you please answer?

Comment: To be honest, I don’t find anywhere in Quran that says like that. You can hate it, or not.

Comment: is there any hadith regarding this?

Comment: Nope, there’s no Hadith regarding this.

Comment: Then, why do people say that "loving own country" is a characteristic of Iman?

Comment: I never heard about this.

Comment: So, If I hate my own country because its dirty, there will be No gunah....Am I correct or wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know how to answer to this one.

Comment: You said that it is NOT haram to hate my own country. Right?

Comment: Well yes, it’s your own choice. You can hate it or not. It’s all up to you. This all what I know.

Comment: So you are saying: It's Not haram. But it may be gunah?

Comment: I seriously don’t know anymore how to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's haram(forbidden)to hate your own country, prophet MOHAMMAD SALLALAHU-ALAIHI-WA-SALLAM said, there are some ancient books in which it's written.

Comment: You need to provide a source.